Add/Sum numbers:areas based on two attributes in QGIS
A newbie here.
I want to sum the areas in GFA for each Parcel based on their AssetClass
After checking few posts in this website, I tried couple of options:
I tried sum (GFA, filter:=''AssetClass''='Hospitality') in the Open field calculator, but didn't work.
I tried creating an expression in attribute table:
attribute( $currentfeature, 'GFA' ) + attribute( get_feature( 'layer name', 'AssetClass',Hospitality), 'Parcel' )

, but I must have puts something wrong and it didn't work as well.
Can you please direct me?


So... for each parcel, you want to sum the area which is dedicated to hospitality use? And then another sum for residential use? And another for retail use?

Hi Erik, correct. sum all the areas in JW-39-A parcel for example which are Residential. Then another one for Retail , the a third one for Hospitality.
Please note, there are over 50 parcels and like 920 area in total to be categorized to there 3 options, so having a manual input is not an option for me :)

Another way to do this if you don't want to do it individually for each AssetClass:

Create a new field which is a concatenation of the fields AssetClass and Parcel :


Use field calculator to calculate the sum based on group by for the new field.


Result with some features highlighted.




Thank you Aquamarine, it worked!!!.
Initially it only worked for Residential and Hospitality and the Retail for some reason was included within Residential, but then I did it again and it worked.

sum("GFA",group_by:="Parcel",filter:="AssetClass"='Hospitality') does what you're looking for. For each other use, change the filter to that exact wording.
Grouping sums the GFA for each parcel separately, and filtering only returns those values with the exact usage you're looking for. Please be aware, that the GFA-attribute needs to be of real, double or integer value for the expression to work.

Hi Erik, thank you for your prompt respond.
For some reason the result is 0 for all the fields. I tried to add a screenshot but I couldn't.
I tried sum("GFA",group_by:="Parcel",filter:="Hospitality")
and
sum("GFA",group_by:="Parcel",filter:='Hospitality') , as Hospital is a 'value' within a 'field', as far I understood from QGIS terminology.
Just to confirm , I put the code in Open field calculator, right?

The sum GFA by Parcel part works, but once I try to filter it, it show result of 0.
sum("GFA",group_by:="Parcel")

Sorry @Majd, I corrected the filter. Naturally you need to tell QGIS in which field to look for which value, not only the value.

Thank you Erik for the clarification.
When I tested the revised code, all the parcels that has hospital as an AssetClass, the code works and sum the GFA for the rows that has hospital. However, in the same parcel where the AssetClass is Retail for example, it shows the sums of the hospitals in that field as well.

Another issue I faced would be for the parcels that don't have Hospitals in it, it shows 0 value. I tried to work around it and add the three Assests as the following, the outcome is incorrect:
sum("GFA",group_by:="Parcel",filter:="AssetClass"='Hospitality')  || sum("GFA",group_by:="Parcel",filter:="AssetClass"='Residential') || sum("GFA",group_by:="Parcel",filter:="AssetClass"='Retail')

That is absolutely intended, correct, and you confirmed you are looking for this behaviour @Majd.

Erik,
Thank you again for your time. You are right, the outcome to get the sum GFA for hospital was achieved for each parcel However, in the same parcel where the AssetClass is Retail for example, it shows the sums of the hospitals in that field as well.
I tried Aquamarine's method without the need to do it individually for each AssetClass, and it worked.
Thank you for your help and expertise again,
